# Using querys to get information from different tables

Tags: sqlite

I am learning SQLite and I'm using [this](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/) database to learn how to correctly use querys but I'm struggling specially when I have to use data from multiple tables to get some information.

For example, with the given database, is there a way to get the first name, last name and the name of songs that every customer has bought?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is a simple SQL `SELECT` query. When you say you're having trouble getting it from multiple tables, I'm not sure if you're trying to get the data from all of the tables in one single query, as that is not necessary. You just need to have multiple instances of the `SELECT` query, just for different tables (and different column names).

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, songName FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use joins to get data from multiple tables. In this case I'd recommend you using inner joins.

In case your are not familiar with joins, [this](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/joins.php) is a very good article that explains the different types of joins supported in SQLite.

> SQLite INNER JOINS return all rows from multiple tables where the join
>   condition is met.

This query will return the first and last name of customers, and the tracks they purchased.

```
select customers.FirstName,
       customers.LastName,
       tracks.name as PurchasedTracks from invoice_items
inner join invoices on invoices.InvoiceId = invoice_items.InvoiceId
inner join customers on invoices.CustomerId = customers.CustomerId
inner join tracks on invoice_items.TrackId = tracks.TrackId
order by customers.LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to study about JOINS:

```
select
  c.FirstName,
  c.LastName,
  t.Name
from invoice_items ii
inner join tracks t on t.trackid = ii.trackid
inner join invoices i on i.invoiceid = ii.invoiceid
inner join customers c on c.customerid = i.customerid
```

In this query there are 4 tables involved and the diagram in the link you posted, shows exactly their relationships. 
So you start from the table `invoice_items` where you find the bought songs and join the other 3 tables by providing the columns `on` which the `join` will be set.
One more useful thing to remember: **aliases** for tables (like `c` for customers) and if needed for columns also.